# concatenating characters using recursion at (c) using only stdio.h library

Tags: c, string, recursion, reverse

Can you help me in my code? I'm trying to concatenate characters using (+) sign but it doesn't work what shall I do? and my homework tells me to do it in that way with only using stdio.h library. that's what I wrote till now and thanks. This is the question-> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2zM1.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
char reverse(char string[], int stringLength){
  static int i; 
  i=stringLength;
  if(stringLength!=0){
    if(i>=0){
      return string[i]+reverse(string[i-1],i--);
    }
  }
  return string;
}

int main(void) {
  int stringLength=0;
  char string[100];

  printf("Enter a string that will be reversed: ");
  scanf("%s",string);

  for (stringLength=0; string[stringLength++]!='\0';){};
  printf("%d", stringLength);
  reverse(string, stringLength);
  printf("the reverse is :%s:\n", string);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `+` operator does not work in C for string concatenation. You gotta either do operator overloading or take a buffer array and swap elements to reverse it.

Comment: The return type is `char` but you are returning a `char *`.

Comment: @Mohammad Abu-Ayyash - Your teacher is confused. In C, there are no methods, and there is no type `String`.

Comment: You don't need to use the `+` operator. What are you trying to achieve with the following statement? `for (stringLength=0;string[stringLength++]!='\0';){};`

Comment: @zois im finding the length of the string

Comment: As @risingStark mentioned, you would need to store the changes you make. I don't think operator overloading is supported in C, so you cannot use `+`. Do you have to implement a recursive solution or are you allowed to swap elements iteratively, starting at the start and end of the string?

Comment: Also pay attention to the return type of `reverse`, you are returning a `char` but you are not using that. I assume you want the reversed string to be stored in place? In other words, after calling `reverse`, `string` should hold the reversed string?

Comment: `stdio.h` is not a library.  It is a header for the standard library.  Perhaps this is mere pedantry, but this particular phrase ("stdio.h library") may be the source of much confusion, as many people seem to conflate headers and libraries.

Comment: `scanf("%s",string);` is a runtime error waiting to happen.  Write `scanf("%99s",string);` to prevent an overflow.

Comment: `for(...){};` is a little weird on the eyes.  The usual style would be to write either `for(...) ;` (probably with some whitespace including a newline before the semi-colon) or `for(...){ ; }` (again, with additional whitespace).